# How do I setup esrally to use with elassandra and my own tests?

Tags: elasticsearch, benchmarking, rally, elassandra, express-cassandra

I'm wondering whether others have attempt benchmarking [Elassandra](https://github.com/strapdata/elassandra/) (more specifically, I'm using [express-cassandra](https://github.com/masumsoft/express-cassandra)) using [esrally](https://github.com/elastic/rally). I'm hoping to not spend to much more time on esrally if that's not a good solution to test Elassandra.

Reading the documentation, it looks like Rally is capable of starting from scratch: Download Elasticsearch, install the source, build it, run it, connect, create a full schema, then start testing with data filling the schema (possibly done with some random data), do queries, ...

I already have everything in place and the only thing I really want to see a few things such as:

- Which of 10 different memory setup is faster.
- Which type of searches work, whether option 1, 2 and 3 from my existing software create drastic slow downs or not...
- Whether insertion while doing searches have a effects on the speed of my searches.

I'm not going to change many parameters other than the memory (`-Xmx`, `-Xms`, maybe some others... like cached row in a separate heap.) For sure, I want to run all the tests with the latest Elassandra and not consider rebuilding or anything of the sort.

From reading the documentation, there is no mention of Elassandra. I found total of TWO PAGES in Google about testing with esrally and Elassandra and that did not boost my confidence that it's doable...

I would imagine that I have to use the [`benchmark-only` pipeline](https://esrally.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pipelines.html#benchmark-only). That at least removes all the gathering of the source, building, etc. I guess it also reduces the number of parameters I get in the resulting benchmark, but I don't need all the details...

Have you had any experience with such a setup? (Elassandra + esrally)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, esrally works with Elassandra by using the `--benchmark-only` option.

To automate the creation of elassandra clusters to benchmark, you could either use [ecm](https://github.com/strapdata/ecm) or [k8s helm chart](https://github.com/strapdata/helm-charts).

For instance, using ccm :

```sh
ecm create bench_cluster -v 6.2.3.10 -n 3 -s -e
esrally --pipeline=benchmark-only --target hosts=127.0.0.1:9200,127.0.0.2:9200,127.0.0.3:9200
ecm remove bench_cluster
```

For testing specific scenarios, you can write custom [tracks](https://github.com/elastic/rally/blob/master/docs/track.rst).

Comment: I ended up writing my own code, but mainly because my customer wanted to test a very large number of rows and it would not be feasible to create a new database each time. At least I couldn't really see how to use `esrally` in such a case.